# Are some alkali metals better conductors than others?

Tags: electricity

I want to know if there is any difference at all between the alkali metals as far as conducting electricity goes.

Comment: The answers show that the resistivities/conductivities don't vary monotonically. I wonder if anyone can give a good explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

```
Li 
Conductivity 1.08×10^7 S/m
Resistivity  9.26×10^(-8) mΩ
Na
Conductivity 2.18×10^7 S/m
Resistivity  4.59×10^(-8) mΩ
K
Conductivity 1.43×10^7 S/m
Resistivity  7.0×10^(-8) mΩ
Rb
Conductivity 8.0×10^6 S/m
Resistivity  1.25×10^(-7) mΩ
Cs
Conductivity 5.3×10^6 S/m
Resistivity  1.9×10^(-7) mΩ
Fr
Conductivity 1.4×10^6 S/m
Resistivity  7.1×10^(-7) mΩ
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the *total resistivity* ρ (in $10^{-6}\ \Omega{}\,\textrm{m}$ at 273.16 K) from [Electrical resistivity of alkaline earth elements](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.555598), 
T. C. Chi, *J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data*, **1979**, *8*, 439-497:

Li  8.53

Na  4.33

K   6.49

Rb 11.54

Cs 18.75

Fr 28.00